# Migrate [selector-infected-wixoss] to [wixoss]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In episode 12 of selector infected WIXOSS, we find out at the end of the episode that the second cour is going to be called "selector spread WIXOSS". As such, the [selector-infected-wixoss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selector-infected-wixoss) tag would be better off being called [wixoss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wixoss), so that the tag name is generic to the whole thing.

(I initially requested a tag migration in a custom flag because this is a trivial change that I don't think really necessitates any sort of community consensus, but here you have it. Though at this point, it would've been faster to just change the tag and copy over the wikis myself...)

Comment: I agree with this retag, but is there any particular reason you didn't just do it yourself? I don't see any reason we need to involve the mods when the tag is only on one question and can easily be fixed by any sufficiently high-rep user in a matter of a few seconds.

Comment: @LoganM Well, I flagged the tag for migration by a moderator because I was feeling lazy and didn't feel like copying over the tag wikis, and whoever reviewed my flag told me to post on meta for "community consensus", so...

Comment: Seems like a custom flag would take longer to explain than copying a single wiki, but okay.

Comment: @LoganM In retrospect, I would be inclined to agree.

Comment: Though there is something to be said for moderators migrating tags - that preserves the edit history on the wikis, which is generally desirable.